# My flutter iOS app hasn't been released yet. How can I know my firebase dynamic link works to open Appstore if the app isn't installed yet?

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up Firebase deep link that will open the Flutter app if it's installed and will open Google Playstore or iOS Appstore respectively if the app isn't installed.

So far, the dynamic link successfully opens the app page in Google Appstore in its internal testing mode (because it's still in internal testing).

But when I tried to test the deep link on iOS device, it shows a Firebase page that says "Save my place in the app. A link will be copied to continue to this page." From my experience, this is the page Firebase showed when the deep link failed.

[image]

When I tapped the button, it indeed shows the Firebase link failed.

[image]

My question is, is this indeed about Firebase base deep link failed, or is it because the app is not released yet on iOS Appstore?

I have set Bundle ID, Appstore ID, and Team ID on the Firebase Apple app. The apple-app-site-association is set up properly from Firebase.

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"TEAMID.com.app.bundle","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

The problem is I cannot publish the app first and then experiment based on that app publish whether the link actually works or not. When the app is published, the link must already work. So I cannot test it beforehand. But I have a feeling the deep link failed, as I think the deep link should open Appstore even though the Appstore will display "Product not found" or similar.

Comment: Deeplink or universal link (deep link starts with appname:// and universal link is a URL https://), Maybe this link can help you on universal link:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/6080-universal-links-make-the-connection

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this issue. I think for the first screen you missing the isi parameter, the second screen maybe caused by you didn't encode the URL